# Read a single int from a file and print it

Tags: haskell

How do I create a program that reads a line from a file, parse it to an int and print it(ignoring exceptions of course). Is there anything like "read" but for *IO String*?

I've got this so far but I couldn't get around the *IO* types:

```
readFromFile = do
   inputFile <- openFile "catalogue.txt" ReadMode

   isbn <- read( hGetLine inputFile)


   hClose inputFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, observe that reading stuff and then immediately printing it can result in mysterious errors:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.0.20160421: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude λ read "123"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The reason is that you don't specify what type you want to read. You can counter this by using type annotations:

```
Prelude λ read "123" :: Integer
123
```

but it is sometimes easier to introduce a little helper function:

```
Prelude λ let readInteger = read :: String -> Integer
Prelude λ readInteger "123"
123
```

Now to the main problem. `read( hGetLine inputFile)` doesn't work because `hGetLine inputFile` returns and `IO String` and `read` needs a `String`. This can be solved in two steps:

```
line <- hGetLine inputFile
let isbn = readInteger line
```

Note two different constructs `<-` and `let .. =`, they do different things. Can you figure out exactly what?

As shown in another answer, you can do it in a less verbose manner:

isbn <- fmap readInteger (hGetLine inputFile)

which is great if you do a simple thing like `read`. But it is often desirable to explicitly name intermediate results. You can use `<-` and `let .. =` constructs in such cases.

Comment: It is still a bit cloudy for me. readInteger is String -> Int so  "let .. = "  will somehow change that to IO String -> IO Integer. Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. `hGetLine inputFile` is `IO String`, but when you say `line <- hGetLine inputFile`, `line` is just `String`. Then `let .. =` doesn't add any IO either. You *will* have to return to IO at the last line of the `do` block, for example, by using `print isbn` (this returns `IO ()`).

Comment: In 'line <- hGetLine inputFile', '<-' converts 'IO String' to 'String'?

Comment: Not really. If you think about IO as a box, and IO String as a string inside a box, then you in fact can never get rid of the box and leave just the content. What `<-` and `fmap` let you do is get inside the box and manipulate its content from within.

Comment: @EricMarchettiSantos Your first proposal (that you are turning a `String -> Int` function into an `IO String -> IO Int` function) was closer to the truth. `line <- hGetLine inputFile; blah` gets turned into `hGetLine inputFile >>= \line -> blah`. In the latter, `(>>=)` is turning your `(\line -> return (read line)) :: String -> IO Int` into `(>>= (\line -> return (read line))) :: IO String -> IO Int`. This combination of `(>>=)` and `return` is common enough that it's given its own name, `fmap`, a function which can indeed turn a `String -> Int` into an `IO String -> IO Int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the type explicitly, change the read line to

```
isbn <- fmap read (hGetLine inputFile) :: IO Int
```

As `hGetLine inputFile` is of type `IO String`, you should use `fmap` to get "inside" to read as an `Int`.

Comment: Not so fast! There are people who are still on ghc 6!

Comment: what does fmap actually do?

Comment: @EricMarchettiSantos It turns a plain function `a -> b` to work under IO as `IO a -> IO b` (it works for other functors as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `readFile` function to convert your file to a string.

```
main = do
  contents <- readFile "theFile"
  let value = read $ head $ lines contents::Int 
  print value
```

You should add better error detection, or this program will fail if there isn't a first line, or if the value is malformed, but this is the basic flow....

Comment: How come value is of type Int instead of IO Int?

Comment: In Haskell's do notation, the value to the left of a `<-` actually has the type of the item with the monad (IO, in this case) removed.  So while it is true that the `readFile` line has type `IO String`, by the next line, value has only type `String`.

Comment: so something like "value <- value" will remove the IO as well?

Comment: Although "remove the IO" isn't quite the correct way to say this, yes, it would.  But I can guarantee you that the Haskell community would consider that bad form.  In general, a variable should not point to two different values, `value` should have a single type.  In fact, in general it is not possible to change the value of a variable, although this example gives you one loophole in that rule....